# Converting x,y to a graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I've a tuple of coordinates `[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 5], [3, 4]` and I want to convert these coordinates into a graph to be used in BFS so each vertex holds a list of its neighbor.

So something like this,

```
0 = [1] 
1 = [0, 2, 3]
2 = [1, 4]
```

Comment: Show us the code you have.  Does it run?  Is there something wrong in the output?

Comment: the correspondance vertex - list of neighbors could be written, for instance, using a _dictionary_. I'd suggest you look at tutorials / read about this.

Comment: @ravenspoint theres no code, i need to convert that tuple into a dictionary where vertex 1 would have ```0,2,3``` as its neighbor. so vertex ```1``` has ```0,2,3``` as its neighbour and do the same for each vertex until i've generated a whole graph that i can then use for BFS.

Comment: If you have no code, then you will get no results.  Write some code, and THEN you can ask about it and we can help you sort out your problem

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
def append_to(out_dict, x, y):
    if x not in out_dict:
        out_dict[x] = []
    if y not in out_dict[x]:
        out_dict[x].append(y)

inpts = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [4, 5], [3, 4]]
out = {}
for inpt in inpts:
    append_to(out, inpt[0], inpt[1])
    append_to(out, inpt[1], inpt[0])
```

Comment: returns no output. i tried calling the function but what would the values for ```out_dict , x , y``` be?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).